# Access property of union type with void and unnamed type

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo

I'm working with GraphQL and at this point in my code, I have a GraphQLError object, which has a property called `extensions` which has a type of `void | { [key: string]: any; }`. This is making it so that if I try to access any property of `extensions`, I get this error:

```
x.extensions.code === 'UNAUTHENTICATED'


Property 'code' does not exist on type 'void | { [key: string]: any; }'.
  Property 'code' does not exist on type 'void'.
```

A proposed solution to accessing properties that don't exist on both types in a union type is here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12815#issuecomment-266193707

```
let pet = getSmallPet();

if ((<Fish>pet).swim) {
    (<Fish>pet).swim();
}
else {
    (<Bird>pet).fly();
}
```

However, I cannot do a type assertion without a type name.

Any ideas on how I can fix this issue?

Regards,
Richard

Comment: Why don't you just use [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-type-assertions) like `if (x.extensions) { x.extensions.code === 'UNAUTHENTICATED' }` or `if (!x.extensions) throw new Error('darn'); x.extensions.code === 'UNAUTHENTICATED'`?

Comment: Also, the type does not need a name. You could write `if ((<{ [key: string]: any; }>x.extensions).code) {`

Answer (score 1):

You can use type guards to narrow the type of the union:

```
declare let o: {
    extensions: void | { [key: string]: any; }
}

o.extensions["test"] // error
if (o.extensions) {
    o.extensions["test"] // ok here
}
```

**Note** Your code will throw an error only if you have `strictNullChecks` turned on